# Sling - Getting child resources of a property

Tags: java, sling

I'm having trouble using the listChildren method in sling and can't for the life of me figure out why. It's a very basic code snippet that looks for a resource named "header" and 
lists it's children with their given properties. The puzzling part is I'm not getting any error messages. Here's my code:

```
Iterator<Resource> serviceList = resource.getChild("header").listChildren()

while(serviceList.hasNext()){
  Resource child = serviceList.next();
  serviceLocationHeader = child.getProperties().get("serviceLocationHeader", "")
}
```

Any ideas? I've been banging my head on this for hours now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not getting any errors, could it be an issue retrieving the content? If for some reason, `listChildren()` returns empty for example?

Also, if you're declaring `serviceLocationHeader` before the `while` loop and only using it after it closes, won't you only be setting it to the value from the last child's property — could there be an issue with this content?

Finally, your call to `child.getProperties().get("serviceLocationHeader", )` is incorrect syntax — it needs a second parameter to specify a default value or a return type.

Comment: Thanks for replying @anotherdave. I don't believe it's how I'm retrieving the content as when I print it in the log nothing shows as well. I'm declaring serviceLocationHeader before the while loop but setting it to a string so don't believe that would be the problem. I made a typo on the .get() call I just updated the post. Any other ideas? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What I mean is, if `serviceLocationHeader` prints nothing to the log, presumably it's hitting your default value, i.e. the empty string rather than returning a property from the JCR. Try changing your method call to `child.getProperties().get("serviceLocationHeader", "foo")` and printing to the logs. If you see `foo` outputted, you know the problem is with your content rather than your code. Then output the node from the JCR directly e.g. using the Default JSON servlet (or check CRXDE if using CQ) and make sure the property is set as expected on the child nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the help @anotherdave, I changed my method call to have a default value of "foo" and when I printed it in the logs I got "foo". When I check CRXDE the property is there. The thing is there is no sling:resourceType but unless I'm wrong everything in sling is a resource so I should still get the property right? Thanks for your time and help on this greatly appreciated!

Comment: No worries Delmon. I'd presume that you would be able to retrieve it alright, even without the resource type set though I'm not 100%. Just noticed that the Sling API doesn't define a `getProperties` method on the `Resource` interface. You could try adapting the resource to a ValueMap in order to read the properties from it? — `child.adaptTo(ValueMap.class).getProperty("serviceLocationHeader", "");`

Comment: Dang I thought that would work, but I'm still getting nothing or the default value when I to print it to the log when I adapt the resource to a valuemap. Any other reasons you could think of I'm really stumped. Thanks again @anotherdave really appreciate the help!

Comment: Hmm, hard to try to debug it further without seeing your content. I'd put in more debugging logs to check where the data is coming back not as you expect. Does the `serviceList` iterator definitely have items? Also, are you sure every child resource has a `serviceLocationHeader` property? Since coming out of the loop, it's going to be set to the value of the last iteration, if the last node doesn't have this property, it will fall back to the default empty string. I'd try removing the iterator — get it working with a single child node/resource first & after that you can refactor/refine it.